# solo.searchtext() deos not scroll expandable list

Tags: android, scroll, robotium

I am using robotium to test my app. Issue is with solo.searchText function. In my app I am using expandale listview to display category values. While testing using robotium I am cross checking whether all the categories are present. I am using the below code for that.

```
    boolean ifCategoryLoadingFailed = false; 
    for(String cat: UnitTestHelperSuite.getInstance().categories){              
        if(solo.searchText(cat,1,true)){
            //LogAdapter.verbose(TAG, "***********Found Category::"+ cat);
            UnitTestingFramework.expdata.exportResult("****","Found Category::"+cat,"Success");
            continue;
        }
        else{
            ifCategoryLoadingFailed = true;
            //LogAdapter.verbose(TAG, "***********Failed to Found Category::"+ cat);    
            UnitTestingFramework.expdata.exportResult("****","Found Category::"+cat,"Failed");
            break;
        }
    }
```

It was working fine before. But now the list is not scrolling. So it is identifying only visible categories. But it is not entering the else condition.Testing is stopping here. How can I make it scrollable? please help me. I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience solo always scrolls down when searching for text. It does not scroll back up though. If your problem is caused by scrolling to the bottom while searching for one value, then the solution is to always call solo.scrollListToTop(listIndex) right before you call searchText() .